# asp.net mvc can't validate input DTO object with ValidationContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I added validation code to my object class using ValidationContext. I added the following but none of the validation attributes are trigger. So far, I 
can't figure why. Any help is appreciated.

```
    public bool Update Book(BookCommand command)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(command, serviceProvider:null, items: null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(command, context, results);


        return UpdateBook(BookTitle , BookCode , AuthorFullName);
    }


public class BookCommand : Command, IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string BookCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Length must be 8 to 16 characters long")]        
    public string AuthorFullName{ get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return new List<ValidationResult>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have validation attributes applied to your model properties `([Required]`, `[StringLength]` etc). What are you trying to do by implementing `IValidatableObject`?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well you have to chose attribute or IValidatableObject

Remove IValidatableObject interface and it should do the work